# Data is not passing from androidX to Firebase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, developer-tools

I am trying to pass  data from androidX to Firebase, it was working perfectly  but now it doesn't work. I am attaching screenshots for the better understanding.

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Users");
```

Main activity:

[image: mainActivity]

[image]

More annoying screenshots of text:

[image: secondphoto]

Also I try it with URL inside the `getInstance()` function
but that doesn't work, either.

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("URL");
private DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Users");
```

Comment: What is the location of your database? Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Path is needed.

Like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(
    "https://database-c249f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

When `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()` does require an URL, this means that you have to run `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(MainActivity.this)` first, in order to initialize the `FirebaseApp`
... unless wanting to connect to another RTDB URL.